# reCAPTCHA does not work in iOS 10 UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, recaptcha

My site is using reCAPTCHA v2.

In the iOS 10 UIWebView, I can not go to the next step when I check "I am not Robot".

However, iOS 10 WKWebView works well.
Also, iOS 11 or later UIWebView works well.
The problem only occurs in iOS 10 UIWebView.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) instead of UIWebView solve this issue for me